# Update several records with the sum of several records from another table - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

product

```
+-------------+------------+
| id_product  | quantity   |
+-------------+------------+
|    15       |       0    |
|    16       |       1    |
|    17       |       3    |
|    18       |       1    |
+-------------+------------+
```

And the other table is a subquery

```
+------------+-----------+
| id_product |   total   |
+------------+-----------+
|     15     |     1     |
|     17     |     1     |
|     18     |     4     |
+------------+-----------+
```

And I want to do is in a single update query, update the table products with the records returned by the subquery, making a sum, I can get one or many records from the subquery.

```
+-------------+------------+
| id_product  | quantity   |
+-------------+------------+
|    15       |       1    |
|    16       |       1    |
|    17       |       4    |
|    18       |       5    |
+-------------+------------+
```

I tried to make this update query, but it does not do what I want.

```
UPDATE product p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id_product, count(*) as total
  FROM othertable
  GROUP BY id_product
) c ON p.id_product = c.id_product
SET p.quantity = c.total;
```

______EDIT______

```
UPDATE product p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id_product, count(*) as total
  FROM othertable
  GROUP BY id_product
) c ON p.id_product = c.id_product
SET p.quantity = p.quantity + c.total
```

Comment: Your query seems right to me. What is it doing that you do not want?

Comment: I have this result:
"Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0"
It doesn't make the sum.

Comment: Solved, I was missing on the set this:
SET p.quantity = p.quantity + c.total

Comment: Please post your final query as answer, and mark it accepted to close this question